# Checking jQuery AJAX Request Status

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i do 2 different ajax request via jQuery and i have to check the other one is active or not. How can i do that ?

one of example from my ajax requests:

```
active_project_categories_ajax = $.ajax(
{
    url: "/ajax/get_skill_list",
    dataType: 'json',
    ......
});
```

i need something like that: active_project_categories_ajax.status()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since you are getting back the XMLHttpRequest object, you can always look at

```
active_project_categories_ajax.readyState
active_project_categories_ajax.status
```

the readyState needs to be 4 for it to be completed (success or error).  so if it is less than 4, then it is still active.

this is the readyState:

```
// states
  const unsigned short UNSENT = 0;
  const unsigned short OPENED = 1;
  const unsigned short HEADERS_RECEIVED = 2;
  const unsigned short LOADING = 3;
  const unsigned short DONE = 4;
```

quoted from: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-xmlhttprequest-interface

You cannot look at the status before readyState becomes 4.  otherwise there may be an exception raised.  (actually, i wrote a php file that return 1MB of data... and when the readyState was 3, the status was also 200.  i suspect the status would be 200 if the readyState stopped at 2 as well).

Comment: this is what I got from the Firebug console: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.status]" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: http://www.somewebsite.com/proj/js/ajax_status/ :: anonymous :: line 54" data: no]

Answer (score 3):

You'd do that by subscribing to [AJAX events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) and updating a status indicator:

```
var status;

$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){
     status = 1;
   },
   complete: function(){
     status = 2;
   }
   // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, `status` is a property of `XMLHttpRequest`, and not a function. `jQuery.ajax` returns an object of `XMLHttpRequest`. Hold on to this as you're already doing:

```
var req = $.ajax(..);
```

Then call `status` on that object when needed, not `status()`

```
req.status
```